# Maximum update depth warning react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am creating a chart in D3 with React. In my chart I have a brush component which manipulates React Hooks. I have the following code :-

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ChartWrapper from './ChartWrapper';
//import ;

function App() {
    let data = [{value: 5, time: 1590034669935}, {value: 4, time: 1590034670435}, {value: 7, time: 1590034670935}, {value: 10, time: 1590034671436}, {value: 4, time: 1590034671936}, {value: 6, time: 1590034672437}, {value: 7, time: 1590034672937}, {value: 4, time: 1590034673437}, {value: 7, time: 1590034673937}, {value: 5, time: 1590034674437}];
   // let [data, setData] = useState([]);
   const style = {
        textAlign: 'center',
    };


    return (
      <div className="App" style={style}>
        <ChartWrapper data={data}  xAxisText = 'Time' yAxisText = 'Values' />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

ChartWrapper.js

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState, useImperativeHandle} from 'react';
import  {select, selectAll, extent, axisBottom, axisLeft, scaleLinear, scaleTime, curve, line, curveCardinal} from 'd3';
import {IsFirstRender} from './IsFirstRender';
import Chart from './Chart';
import NavChart from './NavChart';
import UsePrevious from './UsePrevious';

const MARGIN = {TOP: 50, BOTTOM: 50, LEFT: 50, RIGHT: 50};
const maxData = 10;
export default function ChartWrapper(props) {

    let [selection, setSelection] = useState([props.data[0].time, props.data[1].time]);
    const previousSelection = UsePrevious(selection);
   // let [isDefaultSelection, setDefaultSelection] = useState(true);
    const svgRef = useRef();
    let chart = null;
    let nav = null;
    const navRef = useRef();
    const isMount = IsFirstRender();


    useEffect(
        () => {
                console.log(selection);
                console.log(previousSelection);
                chart = new Chart(MARGIN, svgRef, props.data, props.xAxisText, props.yAxisText);
                nav = new NavChart(MARGIN, navRef, props.data, previousSelection.current, selection, setSelection);





        }, [props.data, previousSelection, selection]        
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <svg ref = {svgRef} width = {700} height = {400}></svg>
            <br /><br/>
            <svg ref = {navRef} width = {700} height = {75}></svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

NavChart.js (This is where I have the brush component)

```
import {select,
    selectAll,
    extent,
    axisBottom,
    axisLeft,
    scaleLinear,
    scaleTime,
    line,
    brushX,
    event
} from 'd3';

const PADDING = {TOP: 10, BOTTOM: 30};

export default class NavChart {
    constructor(MARGIN, svgRef, data, previousSelection, selection, setSelection) {

        this.svg = select(svgRef.current);
        this.MARGIN = MARGIN;
        this.data = data;

        this.chartWidth = this.svg.attr('width') - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
        this.chartHeight = this.svg.attr('height') - PADDING.TOP - PADDING.BOTTOM;

        this.xScale = scaleTime()
                        .domain(extent(
                            this.data.map((d) => d.time)
                        ))
                        .range([0, this.chartWidth]);

        this.yScale = scaleLinear()
                        .domain(extent(
                            this.data.map((d) => d.value)
                        ))
                        .range([this.chartHeight, 0]);

        this.myLine = line()
                        .x((d) => this.xScale(d.time))
                        .y((d) => this.yScale(d.value));

        this.chartArea = this.svg.append('g')
                        .attr('transform', `translate(${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${PADDING.TOP})`);

        this.chartArea.append('rect')
                        .attr('x', 0)
                        .attr('y', 0)
                        .attr('width', this.chartWidth)
                        .attr('height', this.chartHeight)
                        .attr('fill', '#f2f2f2');

        this.pathsG = this.chartArea.append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'pathsG')
                        .attr('transform', `translate(0,0)`);

        this.xAxis = axisBottom(this.xScale);

        this.xAxisG = this.chartArea.append('g')
                                       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${this.chartHeight})`);

        this.xAxisG.call(this.xAxis);

        this.pathsG.selectAll('path')
            .data([this.data])
            .join('path')
            .attr('d', (value) => this.myLine(value))
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', '#D073BA')
            .attr('stroke-width', '1.5');

        this.circlesVar = this.pathsG.selectAll('.circle')
            .data(data);

        this.circlesVar.enter().append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'circle')
            .attr('r', (value) => 
                    value.time > selection[0] && value.time <= selection[1] ? 4 : 2)
            .style('fill', '#D073BA')
            .attr('cx', (d) => this.xScale(d.time))
            .attr('cy', (d) => this.yScale(d.value));

        this.brushG = this.chartArea.append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'brush');

        this.brush = brushX().extent([
            [0, 0],
            [this.chartWidth, this.chartHeight]
        ]).on('start brush end', () => {
            if (event.selection) {
                const timeSelection = event.selection.map(this.xScale.invert);
                setSelection(timeSelection);     // This is where I suspect the error is?
            }
        });

        if (previousSelection === selection) {
            console.log("true");
            this.brushG.call(this.brush)
                        .call(this.brush.move, selection.map(this.xScale));
        }
    }
}
```

UsePrevious.js (A function component used to keep track of variable state)

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function UsePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect( () => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref;
}

export default UsePrevious;
```

Upon running the code, the chart loads fine in the browser but it gets very laggy and I get this error in the console - "

StackTrace ->

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

in ChartWrapper (at App.js:15) 
in div (at App.js:14) 
in App (at src/index.js:10)
in StrictMode (at src/index.js:9) index.js:1 
e index.js:1
React 5
   -> printWarning 
   -> error
   -> checkForNestedUpdates
   -> scheduleUpdateOnFiber
   -> dispatchAction
brush NavChart.js:90  (This is the line "setSelection(timeScale)")
apply dispatch.js:61
customEvent on.js:103
emit brush.js:320
start brush.js:307
move brush.js:251
default each.js:5
move brush.js:240
default call.js:4
NavChart NavChart.js:96    (This is the line "this.brushG.call(this.brush)")
ChartWrapper ChartWrapper.js:29    (This is the line 'nav = new NavChart(MARGIN, navRef, props.data, previousSelection.current, selection, setSelection);')

React 6
  -> commitHookEffectListMount
  -> commitPassiveHookEffects
  -> callCallback
  -> invokeGuardedCallbackDev
  -> invokeGuardedCallback
  -> flushPassiveEffectsImpl
unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
React 3
   -> runWithPriority$1
   -> flushPassiveEffects
   -> commitBeforeMutationEffects
workLoop scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:164

Now I understand that this is probably due to an infinite loop where my component is getting rendered every time useEffect dependancy changes but I don't understand when does this happen. The only time I change the dependency is in the line where i call setSelection(timeSelection) inside the navChart component. Also, this line should only run when the brush is changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass dependency to useEffect, otherwise it will be called any change happens

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function UsePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect( () => {
        ref.current = value;
    }, [value]);
    return ref;
}

export default UsePrevious;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try your suggestion however the code still produces the warning

Comment: can you add stacktrace to the topic?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the solution to my problem. In the 'NavChart.js' when I call the 'on()' method, the if statement is:

```
if (event.selection)
```

This gets called every time the line

```
this.brushG.call(this.brush)
```

is called. This is because the event listener listens to not only changes to brush done via mouse but also changes done programmatically, which I want to avoid. By changing the if statement to:

```
if(event.selection && event.sourceEvent)
```

you get rid of the issue since the event.sourceEvent is null when the event is called due  to programmatic change. Only when the event is fired up due to external events (like mouse move), the sourceEvent will have a value.